# Cosmic ray removal in spectra

Tags: python-3.x

Python developers

I am working on spectroscopy in a university. My experimental 1-D data sometimes shows "cosmic ray", 3-pixel ultra-high intensity, which is not what I want to analyze. So I want to remove this kind of weird peaks.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue in Python 3?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends a on what your data looks like: If you have access to two-dimensional CCD readouts that the one-dimensional spectra were created from, then you can use the lacosmic module to get rid of the cosmic rays there. If you have only one-dimensional spectra, but multiple spectra from the same source, then a quick ad-hoc fix is to make a rough normalisation of the spectra and remove those pixels that are several times brighter than the corresponding pixels in the other spectra. If you have only one one-dimensional spectrum from each source, then a less reliable option is to remove all pixels that are much brighter than their neighbours. (Depending on the shape of your cosmics, you may even want to remove the nearest 5 pixels or something, to catch the wings of the cosmic ray peak as well).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to use the algorithm proposed by Whitaker and Hayes, in which they use modified z scores on the derivative of the spectrum. This medium post explains how it works and its implementation in python https://towardsdatascience.com/removing-spikes-from-raman-spectra-8a9fdda0ac22 .

The idea is to calculate the modified z scores of the spectra derivatives and apply a threshold to detect the cosmic spikes. Afterwards, a fixer is applied to remove the spike points and replace it by the mean values of the surrounding pixels.

```
# definition of a function to calculate the modified z score.
def modified_z_score(intensity):
    median_int = np.median(intensity)
    mad_int = np.median([np.abs(intensity - median_int)])
    modified_z_scores = 0.6745 * (intensity - median_int) / mad_int
    return modified_z_scores  



# Once the spike detection works, the spectrum can be fixed by calculating the average of the previous and the next point to the spike. y is the intensity values of a spectrum, m is the window which we will use to calculate the mean.

def fixer(y,m):
    threshold = 7 # binarization threshold. 
    spikes = abs(np.array(modified_z_score(np.diff(y)))) > threshold
    y_out = y.copy() # So we don't overwrite y
    for i in np.arange(len(spikes)):
        if spikes[i] != 0: # If we have an spike in position i
            w = np.arange(i-m,i+1+m) # we select 2 m + 1 points around our spike
            w2 = w[spikes[w] == 0] # From such interval, we choose the ones which are not spikes
            y_out[i] = np.mean(y[w2]) # and we average the value
 
    return y_out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spectrapepper` for this. The library includes 3 depiking techniques that you can try and use individually or together. An example would be:

```
import spectrapepper as spep

y, x  # y = spectras in rows, x = axis

y = spep.cosmicdd(y, th=100, asy=0.6745, m=5)  # from Whitaker and Hayes
y = spep.cosmicmp(y, alpha=1, avg=2)  # from Barton and Hennelly
y = spep.cosmicmed(y, sigma=1.5)  # elimination by similarity
```

To find the right solution for your problem, you will need to play with the parameters. Consider that eliminating cosmic rays is more complex than it looks with an evolving sea of solutions.